# Kendo MVC- how to add additional items to datasource On MultiselectBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to add extra items(with Name and ID property) to datasource of MultiselectBox after it is own items loaded.

Here is my MultiselectBox:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
   // .Events(e=>
     //   e.Select("Select"))
  .Name("lstStatus")
  .DataTextField("DESCRIPTION")
   .DataValueField("REFERENCEID")

  // .AutoBind(false) 

   .Placeholder("Select Case Status")
   .Value(GetPreSelectedStatusList()) //Adds initial values

   .DataSource(source =>
   {
       source.Read(read =>
       {
           read.Action("GetDefinitionDetails", "Definition", new { definitionCode = "CASE_STATUS", addEmptyRow = false }); 
       })
       .ServerFiltering(true);

   }))
```

Js:

```
var list = $("#lstStatus").data("kendoMultiSelect");
 list.dataSource.add({
     REFERENCEID: 1,
     DESCRIPTION: "SELECT ALL"
 });
```

With this settings all items are loaded to multiselectbox, but when i click to textbox, I cannot see my custom added items(which is "Select All").
When i set AutoBind of Multiselectbox to false, I can see initial values on combobox but when I click on  multiselect's textarea, I see only "Select ALL" item. Other items cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using (Placeholder) which is a property in the MultiSelect

```
.Placeholder("Select All")
```

If not then you can try to add your data in the data bound event also

```
.Events(ev=>ev.DataBound("JavaScriptFunction"))
```

Comment: .Placeholder("Select All") is just a text.I want to add an item that name like "ALL-Selected" which inform user that he doesn't have to select all items to filter(i have filter button on form that send values from Multiselectbox).When i try DataBound i got an javascript error:  "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Comment: I can able to add custom item.It adds custom item after multiselectbox's own items.Is there a way to add my custom item before multiselectbox's data? I mean i want to ad dmy custom data first.

      Another problem is ,as i use open event of Multiselectbox,it adds my custom item everytime when i open the multiselectbox.I need to add item only 1 time.When it is selected other items must be removed from multiselectbox.

Comment: .Events(e => e
           .Open("lstHospitals_select"))----------------- function lstStatus_select() {
        var list = $("#lstStatus").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        list.dataSource.add({
        REFERENCEID: 1,
        DESCRIPTION: "ALL STATUSES"
      });
    }

Comment: In a hurry I guess you can try (workaround) to add your item in the controller before returning it to the multiselect and order them by id considering that you have to give your item the lowest id for it to to appear as the first item, I am sure you can find a better solution in kendo but this is just something to do if you are in a hurry

Comment: Thanks,i will add custom item on controller as a temporary solution.I am still searching for to do with javascrip on view.

Answer (score 0):

Add the item in a `dataBound` event handler:

```
function multiSelectDataBound(e) {
    if (!this._adding) {
        this._adding = true;

        e.sender.dataSource.add({
            REFERENCEID: 1,
            DESCRIPTION: "SELECT ALL"
        });

        this._adding = false;
    }
}
```

The private variable is used to prevent the infinite loop that has caused the javascript error that you have mentioned in @MohQut's answer.